# Favorite Doppler plug-in or software?

Tags: doppler, plug-ins

Recently I had to create some doppler effects of certain sounds and I'm working on Pro Tools 7.4.  I saw at NAB that Pro Tools 8 has a Doppler plug-in, but due to hardware considerations (expansion chassis are a pretty penny) are there any plug-ins that do a good job that work in PT 7.4?

I do have Adobe Audition and had to use that for the effect. It didn't work too bad, but I'd rather keep the workflow on one station (Pro Tools is on a Mac and Audition is on a PC.)

Thanks!

- Ryan

Comment: This may have been well within scope 12 years ago, but now it isn't that useful: plugins move on, and it's really just an opinion post.

Answer (score 4):

Waves Doppler and GRM Tools are my go-to plugs.

Comment: Same here.. :-)

Comment: Waves for me too

Comment: Use Waves, wish i had GRM.

Answer (score 2):

I also Waves now, but before getting Waves I used [Panorama](https://wavearts.com/products/plugins/panorama/) by [WaveArts](https://wavearts.com/). I still really like their plugins.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wavearts.com](https://wavearts.com/images/products/cache/pan5-580x245.jpg))</sub>